# Page title goes missing after WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is used

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am having this problem with webpart in our Sharepoint 2010 site. There are tabs with links like this one:

`<a id="ctl00_m_g_d9ca320c_03e7_455c_9233_3c23891113ed" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_d9ca320c_03e7_455c_9233_3c23891113ed$Itella", "", true, "", "", false, true))">`

After the user clicks on such link page title goes missing. It just disappears from title tag inside head tag. Sharepoint still has this title in metadata, and after refreshing whole page title is back again. I have a feeling that this javascript function is not working well or settings inside are not good. Also it looks like this is generated by sharepoint.

How can I prevent title to disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so at the end this wasn't issue made by WebForm_DoPostBackWithOption :) After hard debuging I made the right question for google and solution is here:

[|handy javascript|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325461/sharepoint-ajax-and-page-title)
That little script really worked!

and possibly also here:
[|Title property|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627378/page-losing-title-after-updatepanel-asyncpostback)
But I haven't tested it, because for me is useless to try changing properties of content page.